# 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh Student@192.168.34.115 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

I'm running this command on my Ubuntu server to send my public key to my Windows. And I got this:

> 'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ote

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error message indicates that one of the systems is a Windows box, not Unix/Linux at all. We can't tell from your question whether that is the system where you are trying to run this command, or the remote system you `ssh` into.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your target is windows machine and it didn't understand cat. Can you give it a try after installing the Cygwin software on Windows machine,